# CRUD operations in WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, odata, wcf-data-services

I have just started looking at oData and started working on WCF Data Services. So what i am asking might not be logical.  I have implented the basic things like exposing the data from entity Framework and consuming it using a client.

Now i want to do the other CRUD operations(create, update, delete) and do some other business logic but the problem is i do not understand where to write the code. For now all i have is SVC file with following code:

```
public class OdataPOCService : DataService< POCEntities>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        }
    }
```

I have worked on WCF is past but, really can not understand where should i write the code that we use to write in Operation Contract.

Kind of not able to complete the picture. The basic questions are:

1. Can and how we perform Insert, Update and Delete.
2. Where to write business logic. Lets say i want to change the date format before exposing.
3. Can WCF data service receive Complex objects like Class and Enums as there is no wsdl.

Some code tutorials or blogs will really help.

Answer (score 1):

I usually place my code like this (Let's say our test model is `BankAccountModel`):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBankAccountService {
    [OperationContract]
    BankAccountModel Insert( BankAccountModel item );

    [OperationContract]
    BankAccountModel Update( BankAccountModel item  );

    [OperationContract]
    void Delete(string ID); 

    //... interface of other methods
}
```

This is the service contract. Expose this, describes how to use your services, but no business logic.
Then you create a class which interface:

```
public class BankAccountService : IBankAccountService {
    public BankAccountModel Insert( BankAccountModel item )
    {
        // business logic for insert 
    }

    public BankAccountModel Update( BankAccountModel item  )
    {
        // business logic for update 
    }

    public void Delete(string ID)
    { 
       // business logic for delete
    }
}
```

This will be your back-end/business logic. Don't expose this class. Client doesn't have (and is not allowed) to know what is here.

For passing complex object like `BankAccountModel` you have to define it as `DataContract` and the properties you want to serialize as `DataMember`. Simple example:

```
[DataContract]
public class BankAccountModel {
    [DataMember]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733811(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks DDan. I am familiar with this stuff. But this seems like a WCF service. Does this work with WCF oData service as well. Could you please confirm. I dont think this this way it will remain Rest and will provide all filtering and other things oData provide.

Comment: I can't confirm at the moment, I never used oData service before. This must be the way to do it, so I guess it must be possible. I will get back on this.